# How can I create a field to change the URL in simple_html_dom?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm using `simple_html_dom`, to extract the Name, price and if they are, the manufacturer in a website.

Now, I want to create a script to do a field where you have to put the URL you wan't to extract in the website.

When you tap in the bottom "Extract", the script change the URL in my code:

```
 $html->load_file ('URL');
```

to the URL we have put in that field.

How can I do that?

---

Hello @Richard i have done a html form and it's Working on the action_page.php:

That's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="action_page.php" method="get">
  URL:<br>
  <input type="text" name="URL" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And this one the action_page.php:

```html
<html>
<body>

The URL is: <?php echo $_GET["URL"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, how can i do for remplace the URL in my code to extract the prices, for the one we put in the extractor.php and we have also in the action_page.php ?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at the HTML `form`-command. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp. Try it and show us your try, than we could help you.

Comment: @Richard i have eddited my answer in front

Comment: You have the URL in your `$_GET["URL"]` - variable you could set it in like this `$html->load_file ($_GET["URL"]); ` and in your `action_page.php` you could do an `require('extractor.php');`.

Comment: Many thanks @Richard !! I have almost done!! 

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, i have made:

```
$html->load_file ($_GET["URL"]);
```

And in the action_page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="action_page.php" method="get">
  URL:<br>
  <input type="text" name="URL" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you! And best regards